# Sidebar - Custom VisualForce for record creation

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I want to create a simple home page narrow component where you could, for example, type a new account name and click save to create the record. I'm doing a more specific thing in reality but the base concept is the same.

I haven't created a VF page for this region before and don't know where to start. Are there specific dimensions you should lock to? Specific models I should follow?  Does anyone have any good examples of a basic VF home page narrow component?

Comment: There's nothing special about it, really. I recommend you start developing and see if you run into any *specific* issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link can help you. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=home_page_components_custom_create.htm&language=en_US&type=0

And for a good design I think you can use this for your homepage component :)
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/

Start your VF and Apex class and Add it to your homepage